# Отправить запрос get

Tags: php, html, get

Не получается отправить get запрос. Надо выбрать один из тре ценноков или ввести свою цену и отправить это методом get, пока что просто в адресную сртоку.

```
<form action="" method="get">
<fieldset>
<input type="button" name="price" value="500р">
<input type="button" name="price" value="1000р">
<input type="button" name="price" value="5000р">
<input type="text" name="other_price" placeholder="Своя цена">
<input type="submit" name="price_btn">
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Ввести пятаюсь так

```
<?php
    $_GET['price'];
?>
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: `$_GET['price'];` - это переменная, вы ее не выводите. Вывести можно через `echo $_GET['price'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для автоматической отсылки формы по нажатию кнопки:

```
<input type="submit" ...
```

вместо

```
<input type="button" ...
```

Имейте в виду, что если будет нажата последняя кнопка, значения с ключом `'price'` в запросе не будет.

Или так - с радио-кнопками вместо обычных кнопок:

```js
// this script is here only to demonstrate submitted form data 
$("form").submit(function(e) {
  console.log($(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="get">
  <fieldset>
    <label><input type="radio" name="price" value="500р">500р</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="price" value="1000р">1000р</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="price" value="5000р">5000р</label><br/>
    <label><input type="radio" name="price" value="custom">Своя цена</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name="custom_price" placeholder="Своя цена">
    <input type="submit" name="price_btn">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Я понял свою ошибку, но вопрос остается. Как выбраненую или введеную сумма отправить `get` запросом?

Comment: @MegaRoks Поставьте `type="submit"` всем кнопкам.

Comment: Но тогда посто по нажатии будет отправляться, как сдеалт ьчтобы пользовательно выбрал или ввел цену, а потом нажал на `price_btn` и только тогда отправился запрос

Answer (score 0):

Две формы. В одной человек может выбрать цену, во второй ввести свое значение.

```
<h3>По нажатию выбранной цены, просто две формы</h3>
<form action="" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="submit" name="price" value="500р">
        <input type="submit" name="price" value="1000р">
        <input type="submit" name="price" value="5000р">
    </fieldset>
</form>
<form action="" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="text" name="custom_price" placeholder="Своя цена">
        <input type="submit" name="price_btn">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Вариант с выбором

```
<h3>Выбор из цен</h3>
<form action="" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <label><input type="radio" name="price" value="500"> 500р</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="price" value="1000"> 1000р</label>
        <label><input type="radio" name="price" value="5000"> 5000р</label>
        <input type="text" name="other_price" placeholder="Своя цена">
        <input type="submit" name="price_btn">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```